snowflake update using same table as source and target
I have a below query in SQL server which i need to convert into a snowflake compatible query.
 UPDATE t1 set t1.RMId = null from Client t1 
inner join Main t2  on t1.Code=t2.Registration_No 
inner join Mapping t3  on  t2.ID=t3.Id
 where  isnull( t1.Code,'')!=''  and t1.date >=  Convert(date,Getdate() - 30)

I'm not sure how to use multiple joins in snowflake , or what happens when there is no joining condition between source and target table. Below is the query I've written so far, but I'm not sure how it will work or gives expected result as same as above query from sql server
UPDATE Client t1
SET t1.RMId = NULL
FROM ( SELECT * from Client t1
INNER JOIN Main t2 ON t1.Code = t2.Registration_No
INNER JOIN Mapping t3 ON t2.ID = t3.Id ) t2
WHERE COALESCE(t1.Code, '') != ''
  AND t1.date >= CURRENT_DATE() - 30;


I prefer to write my updates to use only one source by encapsulating multi source update conditions inside a temp table/view. See if this helps
create or replace temporary table codes_to_update as

select registration_no as code
from main
where registration_no <> '' and id in (select id from mapping);


update client 
set client.rmid = null
from codes_to_update
where client.date >= current_date() - 30 and client.code = codes_to_update.code;


you could try as follows.
--untested
UPDATE Client t1
SET t1.RMId = NULL
from Client t1
JOIN Main t2 ON t1.Code = t2.Registration_No
JOIN Mapping t3 ON t2.ID = t3.Id  t2
WHERE COALESCE(t1.Code, '') != ''
  AND t1.date >= CURRENT_DATE() - 30;


Thanks for your reply. Looks like the query you have shared is similar to the one I have prepared. Snowflake considers source and target tables as completely different tables in update statement. So I want to know how the source and target are being joined in this case when there is no joining condition given

@curry_b ,  sorry i did not see that t1 is not joined, with your t2 & t3, you don't have any columns on which you can join t1 with t2 or t3 ?
